# Adding a calculated field to a Query at run time

Tags: delphi, calculated-field

I'm getting data using a query in Delphi, and would like to add a calculated field to the query before it runs.  The calculated field is using values in code as well as the query so I can't just calculate it in SQL.

I know I can attach an `OnCalcFields` Event to actually make the calculation, but the problem is after adding the calculated field there are no other fields in the query...

I did some digging and found that all of the field defs are created but the actual fields are only created

```
if DefaultFields then
    CreateFields
```

Default Fields is specified

```
procedure TDataSet.DoInternalOpen;
begin
    FDefaultFields := FieldCount = 0;
    ...
end;
```

Which would indicate that if you add fields you only get the fields you added.

I would like all the fields in the query AS WELL AS the ones I Add.

Is this possible or do I have to add all the fields I'm using as well?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use the values from the code in your SQL....I build dynamic SQL statements regularly that use values from the code in the SQL....

Comment: see my answer for a new way to do this since delphi Berlin

Comment: did you try to PREPARE the query ? It could have created fielddefs (not field objects yet though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi now has the option to combine automatic generated fields and calculated fields : [Data.DB.TFieldOptions.AutoCreateMode](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Data.DB.TFieldOptions.AutoCreateMode) an enumeration of type [TFieldsAutoCreationMode](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Data.DB.TFieldsAutoCreationMode). This way you can add your calculated fields at runtime. Francois wrote in his answer how to add a field at runtime.

Different modes of TFieldsAutoCreationMode :

- **acExclusive**

  When there are no persistent fields at all, then automatic fields are created. This is the default mode.
- **acCombineComputed**

  The automatic fields are created when the dataset has no persistent fields or there are only calculated persistent fields. This is a convenient way to create the persistent calculated fields at design time and let the dataset create automatic data fields.
- **acCombineAlways**

  Automatic fields for the database fields will be created when there are no persistent fields.

Comment: It looks like this allows combining design time calculated fields and run-time data fields. Did you test/succeed what you claim in the answer?

Comment: This isn't math homework where you have to 'proof' everything. The code to create a field at runtime is described in another answer

Comment: Well, the documentation does not say what you claim.

Comment: Tested in C++ Builder XE8, everything work OK. This is simpler solution than that of Francois, because you dont have to add additional code to your project.

Answer (score 16):

**Nothing prevents you from creating all the fields first in your code,

then add your calculated fields.**

You can either use a "hacked type" to use the protected CreateFields:

```
type
  THackQuery = class(TADOQuery)
  end;
[...]
  MyQuery.FieldDefs.Update;
  THackQuery(MyQuery).CreateFields;
```

or borrowing some code from CreateFields:

```
  MyQuery.FieldDefs.Update;
  // create all defaults fields
  for I := 0 to MyQuery.FieldDefList.Count - 1 do
    with MyQuery.FieldDefList[I] do
      if (DataType <> ftUnknown) and not (DataType in ObjectFieldTypes) and
        not ((faHiddenCol in Attributes) and not MyQuery.FIeldDefs.HiddenFields) then
        CreateField(Self, nil, MyQuery.FieldDefList.Strings[I]);
```

then create your calculated fields:

```
  MyQueryMyField := TStringField.Create(MyQuery);
  with MyQueryMyField do
  begin
    Name := 'MyQueryMyField';
    FieldKind := fkCalculated;
    FieldName := 'MyField';
    Size := 10;
    DataSet := MyQuery;
  end;
```

Comment: In the case where you are subclassing a TQuery or another TDataset  type, you don't need to "hack" to access protected fields.  This answer is the correct way to go when you are (a) adding a calculated field in code, and (b) the entire thing is in code such as you are writing a custom query or component  entirely in code.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add all fields in addition to your calculated field.

Once you add a field, you have to add all of the fields that you want in the data set.

Delphi calls this persistent fields versus dynamic fields. All fields are either persistent or dynamic. Unfortunately, you can't have a mixture of both.

Another thing to note, from the documentation is

> Persistent fields component lists are
>   stored in your application, and do not
>   change even if the structure of a
>   database underlying a dataset is
>   changed.

So, be careful, if you later add additional fields to a table, you will need to add the new fields to the component. Same thing with deleting fields.

If you really don't want persistent fields, there is another solution. On any grid or control that should show the calculated field, you can custom draw it. For example, many grid controls have a OnCustomDraw event. You can do your calculation there.

Answer (score 2):

If you have know your to be calculated fields names at runtime, you can use something like that.

```
var
 initing:boolean;

procedure TSampleForm.dsSampleAfterOpen(
  DataSet: TDataSet);
var
 i:integer;
 dmp:tfield;
begin
if not initing then
 try
  initing:=true;
  dataset.active:=false;
  dataset.FieldDefs.Update;
  for i:=0 to dataset.FieldDefs.Count-1 do
  begin
   dmp:=DataSet.FieldDefs.Items[i].FieldClass.Create(self);
   dmp.FieldName:=DataSet.FieldDefs.Items[i].DisplayName;
   dmp.DataSet:=dataset;
   if (dmp.fieldname='txtState') or (dmp.FieldName='txtOldState') then
   begin
     dmp.Calculated:=true;
     dmp.DisplayWidth:=255;
     dmp.size:=255;
   end;
  end;
  dataset.active:=true;
 finally
  initing:=false;
 end;
end;

procedure TSampleForm.dsSampleAfterClose(
  DataSet: TDataSet);
var
 i:integer;
 dmp:TField;
begin
if not initing then
begin
 for i:=DataSet.FieldCount-1 downto 0 do
 begin
  dmp:=pointer(DataSet.Fields.Fields[i]);
  DataSet.Fields.Fields[i].DataSet:=nil;
  freeandnil(dmp);
 end;
 DataSet.FieldDefs.Clear;
end;
end;

procedure TSampleForm.dsSampleCalcFields(
  DataSet: TDataSet);
var
 tmpdurum,tmpOldDurum:integer;
begin
  if not initing then
    begin
      tmpDurum := dataset.FieldByName( 'state' ).AsInteger;
      tmpOldDurum:= dataset.FieldByName( 'oldstate' ).AsInteger;
      dataset.FieldByName( 'txtState' ).AsString := State2Text(tmpDurum);
      dataset.FieldByName( 'txtOldState' ).AsString := State2Text(tmpOldDurum);
    end;
end;

procedure TSampleForm.btnOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if dsSample.Active then
   dsSample.Close;
 dsSample.SQL.text:='select id,state,oldstate,"" as txtState,"" as txtOldState from states where active=1';
 dsSample.Open;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //assume we have an fdquery named  FDQuery1
    //we write this code in AfterOpen section
```

note:
This method have a problem
The calculated field is placed in place of the last field
To solve this problem, it is enough to add an additional field in query, for example, consider the value zero as the final field
like this :

```
select * , 0 as myfield from mytable


procedure Tform1.FDQuery1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
 i : Integer;
 aField : TField;
begin
    FDQuery1.Close;
    for i := 0 to FDQuery1.FieldDefs.Count - 1 do begin
     aField := FDQuery1.FieldDefs [ i ].CreateField ( fdQuery1 );
    end;
    aField.DataSet := fdQuery1;
    with aField do
    begin
      Name := 'myField';
      FieldKind := fkCalculated;
      FieldName := 'myField';
      Size := 10;
      DataSet := FDQuery1;
    end;
    fdQuery1.FieldDefs.Update;
    fdQuery1.AfterOpen:=nil;
    fdQuery1.Open;
    ShowMessage(FDQuery1.FieldByname('myField').AsString);
end;
```

now you can write onClacField method for myField