# How do I display values in a DBGrid that are different from those in the database?

Tags: database, delphi, dbgrid

**PROBLEM**

[image]

I have `DBGdrid` and there are columns what show `ID's` from an MS Access database. How can I change them to real values like `item name, client name, employee name`?

I have code (test code, I just tried to get all items names from table and I could save them to array or variable and change with `DBGrid` values what show id's), but I don't know how to change `DBGrid` value fields.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i,j:integer; mas:string;
begin
Button1.Enabled := false;
Button2.Enabled := true;
Button3.Enabled := true;

Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM items_specification';

Form1.ADOQuery1.Open;
j:= Form1.ADOQuery1.RecordCount;
Form1.ADOQuery1.Close;

i:=1;

repeat
Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM items_specification WHERE item_id = :ID';
Form1.ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('ID').Value := i;
Form1.ADOQuery1.Open;
mas:= Form1.ADOQuery1['item_name'];
Form1.ADOQuery1.Close;
inc(i);
ShowMessage(mas) ;
until (i = j+1);
```

Maybe you have any suggestions how to solve the problem, I will appreciate that.

In MS Access I have made look up to show names [there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpXxL.jpg), mby there is some way to do that in `DBGrid`?

**UPDATED**

But code doesn't matter.. My big question is how to set item name, client name and employee name in `DBGrid` (in values not column title)?! In MS Access those fields where is id is number, so if I even edit `DBGrid` it don't allow me to change value to string.. Only way what I could imagine is to broke relationships in MS Access and change fields to `ShortText`, but I think is not the best way.

Comment: In `ShowMessage` show variable `mas`. In `mas` I save item name what i get from repeating query from 1st to last by id. But code doesn't matter.. I ask how to show right information in `DBGrid` and if it's possible without deleting relationship in DB. Because in db it's number field, but in `DBGrid` I need to show it as string.

Comment: Forget the DBGrid, it is a "red herring", just say in plain words what you are trying to do.  It sounds like you are wanting to look up a text value based on a numeric key.

Comment: What do you mean by update query? In `DBGrdi` what you see in picture I connected to `services` table, and there is field `item_id`, `client_id`, `employee_id`. `item_name` (same as client name, employee name) field is in another table for example `item_specification` table have `item_name` field. So how can I change `item_name` field from `item_specification` table with `item_id` field in `services` table in `DBGrid`?

Comment: Yep, i want some kind of look up like in MS Access or mby some peace of code or query to change 3 fields in `DBGrid` with other.
And I don't know why link don't work for you, because I just tried in `Chrome, Firefox` (using Win10) and links are working. If you have any suggestions how to make links better tell me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show values in a `DBGrid` cell that are not actually in your database, you can add a `calculated field`.

You double click on the source: `ADOQuery1` and add all the fields you want to the available field list. Then you add a new field.
*(I've left the other fields empty because I'm lazy, but you should make sure to add all the fields from the database that you want to list)*

[image]

You set the properties as required (don't forget that radiobutton in the middle of the dialog).

In your form a new Field will be added matching the name you gave in the `Name` box *(prefixed with the dataset name)*.
You then double click on the `OnCalcFields` event of the dataset (`ADOQuery1`) and insert to code to populate your calculated fields, e.g.:

```
procedure TForm44.ADOQuery1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  ADOQuery1ExampleCalc1.AsString:= 'Prefix:'+DataSet.FieldByName('Field1').AsString;
  ADOQuery1ExampleCalc2.AsInteger:= DataSet.FieldByName('Amount').AsInteger+100;
end;
```

**Note**
If you display many rows, you will find that it may display slowly. In that case replace the `FieldByName` with the actual field reference, e.g. `ADOQuery1Field1`.
FieldByName does a lookup every time it's invoked which slows things down.

**Note 2**
You can also combine data from 2 database tables in the OnCalcFields event, but beware that event gets called once for every row on display, so make sure your lookup is snappy.
If not it may be a better idea to change the SQL statement in your query.

**Further reading**
See here (if you want to do this at run time): [Adding a calculated field to a Query at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523697/adding-a-calculated-field-to-a-query-at-run-time)

Here's the official documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Defining_a_Calculated_Field

Sample code: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Programming_a_Calculated_Field

Comment: Seems like it's what I need, but I still can't understand how to do that. I can't even explain what is wrong. Maybe there are some way how to cantact with you to show you what I done and maybe you could explain me what i'm doing wrong and how to make calculated field on my example.

Comment: If you want to combine data from different tables, then you'll need to do a join: `select names.name, items_specification.id, items_specification.someotherfield from items_specification inner join names on (items_specification.name_id = names.id)`   Read up on SQL and joins.

Comment: The "answer" currently marked as THE answer does not seem to address the OP's ACTUAL problem (which he doesn't know how to express) - which appears to be actually an SQL issue and needing to do a join as Johan suggests in a comment.

It appears that the OP wants to replace the ID's in one table that are referencing another table with a value from a different column in that table.

The marked answer - answers the title queestion, but not the underlying problem.